# Kotlin Compose Multiplatform, include folders in package used at runtime

Tags: gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I would like to add a folder named lib to the package. It contains dlls I use with JNI. I also have a folder named conf with a json file. Both are in the top directory of the project.
The lib folder is needed only on Windows. So,

- How can I add this 2 folders in the final package to use them at runtime ?
- And how can I handle the path to distinguish when I run the app with my editor, or whit the final package ?

I know there is this method: `resources.srcDirs("resources")`, but I'm not sure it's good to use this with dlls and it's will be nice if the json file can be edited by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following line in the nativeDistributions to specify where I put my resources, but this only includes them in the app jar, not inside the actual resource folder that is created. I don't know a better solution. Does this help?

```
appResourcesRootDir.set(project.layout.projectDirectory.dir("src/main/resources"))
```